# Run portion of Python code in parallel from a Streamlit app

Tags: python, parallel-processing, streamlit

I have a Streamlit app that configures a batch of energy models to run and a separate module of code that builds and runs those models in parallel. The exiting code currently uses SCOOP (https://scoop.readthedocs.io/en/0.7/) to handle multiprocessing, which typically runs with `python -m scoop run.py`. Is there a way to run Streamlit but pass in that flag?

I've also tried using subprocesses to run the file that uses SCOOP like:

```
    with st.spinner('Running batch'):
        p = subprocess.run(["python", "-m scoop", "run.py"])
```

But this returns returncode 1 saying `/venv/bin/python: No module named  scoop`. Is running with SCOOP like this even possible, or do I need to refactor to use the Python built-in multiprocessing library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With code like this, you need to be extra careful to specify which `python` you are referring to

`p = subprocess.run(["python", "-m scoop", "run.py"])`

When you do this, you will get the version of Python that is on your system path, not necessarily the venv that you are using.

You are better off running the line as
`p = subprocess.run(["/path/to/python", "-m scoop", "run.py"])`

Edit: You could also run something like this to detect the executable that the Streamlit code is running under

`subprocess.run([f"{sys.executable} ", "-m scoop", "run.py"])`

Comment: Thanks Randy, huge help getting me unblocked. Managed to get this working with this line:

`p = subprocess.Popen([f"{sys.executable} -m scoop run.py {RUN_ID}"],stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT,shell=True)`

It's really finicky, so I ended up passing the flag in with the `sys.executable`, otherwise it read it in as another command and not a flag. There's also a trailing space after `executable} ` that was messing things up for some reason *shrug. Working now though! Thanks!